# How to add Imageview On Transparent Area of Image

Tags: ios, iphone, image, image-processing, uiimageview

I am developing color Photo Frame app but I am stuck in one part. I have lots of frame in my app. So I want to Find Transparent area of my app and put UIImageView programmatically on that part. But i was trying number of code to read pixel by pixel and many more but nothing works

[Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkKrL.png)

here code which i use for find area of transparent

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

unsigned char *rawData = malloc(image.size.width * image.size.height * 4);

NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;

NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * image.size.width;

NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, image.size.width, image.size.height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width , image.size.height), imageRef);

CGContextRelease(context);

unsigned char * rawData2 = malloc(image.size.width * image.size.height * 4);

BOOL isBlank = YES;

for(int index=0;index<(image.size.width * image.size.height * 4);index+=4)
{
    if(index%4==0)
    {
        if(rawData[(int)index+3]==0)
        {
            rawData2[(int)index]   = rawData[(int)index];
            rawData2[(int)index+1] = rawData[(int)index+1];
            rawData2[(int)index+2] = rawData[(int)index+2];
            rawData2[(int)index+3] = rawData[(int)index+3];
            isBlank=NO;
        }
        else
        {

            rawData2[(int)index]   = 0;
            rawData2[(int)index+1] = 0;
            rawData2[(int)index+2] = 0;
            rawData2[(int)index+3] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

How to find transparent area frame(CGreact) in the imageview?

Comment: If you read pixel by pixel, you will surely get rectangle of pixels each having rgba(0,0,0,0) value

Comment: I think you need to calculate coordinate and pixel of Main imageview then add your sub imageview to transparency  place.

Comment: yes i was try getting every 4 pixel  and search transparent area but there are 5 area so how can i find cgrect from pixel

Comment: Do you get that partially transparent image in runtime?
If you set it in Storyboard/Xib, you could just add empty image views in places, and just fill them with images.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Evgeniy Please check this  image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkKrL.png